# como crear una lista condicional

Tags: python-3.x

Me gustaría que mi programa obvié las palabras dentro de comillas dobles, en lugar de devolverme

```
[['variable1', '=', '"soy', 'un', 'string"'],
 ['variable2', '=', '"yo', 'tambien"'],
 ['funcion("yo', 'un', 'argumento")']]
```

me devuelva

```
[['variable1', '=', '"soy un string"'],
 ['variable2', '=', '"yo tambien"'],
 ['funcion("yo un argumento")']]
```

aqui dejo mi codigo para que le echen una ojeada

```
code = """
variable1 = \"soy un string\"
variable2 = \"yo tambien\"
funcion(\"yo un argumento\")
"""
code = code.split("\n")
code = list(filter(None,code))
code = list(map(lambda a: a.split(" "),code))
```

Comment: Creo que eso requiere recorrer a mano el string para ubicar las cremillas dobles, o sea, varias líneas de código en lugar de una simple función. ¿Es aceptable? ¿Puedes usar librerias, expresiones regulares?

Comment: @CandidMoe no, lo quiero hacer sin utilizar librerías xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: en el caso `funcion("yo', 'un', 'argumento")`, el parsing que propones no es consistente con el requerimiento y el resultado correcto es otro.

El problema con la extracción de string es que hay que hacerlo a mano.

Este código procesa líneas bien formadas (con un número par de cremillas dobles):

```
def extraer(texto):
    largo = len(texto)
    resultado = []
    i = 0
    while i < largo:
        if texto[i] == '"':
            fin = texto[i+1:].find('"') + 1
            resultado.append(texto[i:i + fin + 1])
            i += fin + 1
        else:
            fin = i
            while fin < largo and texto[fin] != '"':
                fin += 1
            resultado.extend(texto[i:fin].split())
            i = fin
    return resultado
```

Recorres el texto caracter por caracter. Si el caracter es cremillas dobles, usas `find` para encontrar la siguiente comilla, y teniendo los dos indices, extraes el string completo, agregandolo a la salida.

Si te encuentras con algo distinto a las cremillas dobles, iteras sobre el texto hasta encontrar una cremilla doble (o el fin del texto). Con estos dos indices puedes extraer el texto, aplicarle `split` para dividirlo y luego lo agregas a la salida.

#### Demo

```
code = """
variable1 = \"soy un string\"
variable2 = \"yo tambien\"
\"un string al\" comienzo de la linea
con \"otro string\" entremedio
mientras "que aqui" hay "dos strings" y
no string at all
funcion("yo un argumento")
"""
code = code.split("\n")
code = list(filter(None,code))
for linea in code:
    print(extraer(linea))
```

produce:

```
['variable1', '=', '"soy un string"']
['variable2', '=', '"yo tambien"']
['"un string al"', 'comienzo', 'de', 'la', 'linea']
['con', '"otro string"', 'entremedio']
['mientras', '"que aqui"', 'hay', '"dos strings"', 'y']
['no', 'string', 'at', 'all']
['funcion(', '"yo un argumento"', ')']

Process finished with exit code 0
```